# Can't fix regex expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to make my php links look pretty with RewriteRule in .htaccess. I have following expression which works fine :

`RewriteRule post-([^/]+)/?$ post.php?post_title=$1 [L]`

So, if I enter something like mysite/post-first-post it works great. Problems started when I wanted to exclude 'post-' as well, and make it just mysite/post-title. Whatever I do, it just wouldn't work. if I try just:

`([^/]+)/?$ post.php?post_title=$1 [L]`

I get 'post.php' as my title value instead. If I try to put any kind of 'not char' 'nothing' expression, I just geat the same result with 'p' eaten (ost.php)...

Comment: Could you post a list of desired inputs and outputs that demonstrate your various expected use cases?

Comment: I am using GET to show single post by title. So, my original links looks like this mysite/post.php?post_id=post_title
And I want it to look like mysite/post_title

Comment: The question title is pretty generic and could be more descriptive.

Comment: Yeah... sorry, but when I try to title it something like 'regex match for nothing' or anything similar, I find bunch of questions with almost 100% same title with completely different problem than what I am having...

Comment: O.K, this actually worked: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ post.php?post_id=$1 [L] Tho, I have no idea how and why. I mean, I understand why it works for post, but I dont understand why I don't get error on other pages like mysite/about...